# For n = 2 ... 11 set up Vandermonde matrix A of size m × n and for each n given data set a. Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am given set of 50 data points with values {a^(i),b^(i)} for i=1,...,50
stored in the arrays a and b.
I know that the Vandermonde matrix A has size m x n, where n = 2 ... 11 and m is the size of the array a.

I want to to fit the data with a polynomial of degree (n − 1), for n = 2,...,11. To do that for each n I have to set up the Vandermonde matrix A of size m × n.

The Vandermonde matrix A solves the following equation: 
`A^T*A*x = A^T*b`

Where the A^T is the transpose matrix and I have b already given. 
Also we know that `Aij = (a^(i))^(j−1)` for j = 1,...,n,
What confuses me is how to set the matrix for n = 2,..,11.

What my line of thought is:
I have `m = length(a);` this will set up m = 50;

n = 11;

Then `A=ones(m,n);` This creates a matrix A filled with ones that has the correct size.

However I am not sure how to populate the matrix. 
I wrote the following for loop which I thought will populate the matrix:

```
for n = 2:11
    j=n;
    for i = 1:50
        A(i,n) = (a^(i))^(j-1);
    end
end
```

Could you help me please with setting up the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`vander`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vander.html) function. However, `vander` will return an m x m matrix, which is usually used to fit the data to a polynomial of degree (m-1). Since you want to fit to a polynomial of degree (n-1), you only need the last n columns of that matrix.

Here's the code:

```
A = vander(a);
A = A(:,end-n+1:end);
```